# How to come back in previous textfield if all textfield is empty?

Tags: swift

[if all textfield is fill it will easily come back but if all textfield is empty and i click on last textfield then i want to come back to the previous textfield and so on how i achieved this please help me ]

```
import UIKit
    class OTPVC: CommonViewController,UITextFieldDelegate   {
    @IBOutlet weak var aboutOtp: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstOtptxt: UITextField!

        @IBOutlet weak var secondOtptxt: UITextField!

        @IBOutlet weak var thirdOtptxt: UITextField!

        @IBOutlet weak var fourthOtptxt: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
           setUpView()

        firstOtptxt.delegate = self
        secondOtptxt.delegate = self
        thirdOtptxt.delegate  = self
        fourthOtptxt.delegate = self

                    }
    private func setUpView()      {
        aboutOtp.makeCornerRadius(10)
           }


        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            if ((textField.text?.count)!) < 1 && (string.count > 0) {
                if textField == firstOtptxt{
                    secondOtptxt.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
                if textField == secondOtptxt {
                    thirdOtptxt.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
                if textField == thirdOtptxt {
                    fourthOtptxt.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
                if textField == fourthOtptxt {
                    fourthOtptxt.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
                textField.text = string
                return false
            } else if (((textField.text?.count)!) >= 1) && (string.count == 0) {
                if textField == secondOtptxt {
                    firstOtptxt.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
                if textField == thirdOtptxt {
                    secondOtptxt.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
                if textField == fourthOtptxt {
                    thirdOtptxt.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
                if textField == firstOtptxt {
                    firstOtptxt.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
                textField.text = string
                return false
            }
            else if ((textField.text?.count)!) >= 1 {
                textField.text = string
                return false
            }
            return true
               }

               }
[if all textfield is fill it will easily come back but if all textfield is empty and i click on last textfield then i want to come back to the previous textfield and so on how i achieved this please help me ]
```

[if all textfield is fill it will easily come back but if all textfield is empty and i click on last textfield then i want to come back to the previous textfield and so on how i achieved this please help me ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protocol MyTextFieldDelegate: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, didDeleteBackwardAnd wasEmpty: Bool)
                            }
class MyTextField: UITextField     {
    override func deleteBackward() {
        // see if text was empty
        let wasEmpty = text == nil || text! == ""
        // then perform normal behavior
        super.deleteBackward()
        // now, notify delegate (if existent)
        (delegate as? MyTextFieldDelegate)?.textField(self, didDeleteBackwardAnd: wasEmpty)
            }
            }
```

[just put a delegate method and its work fine in my project yippy]

Answer (score 0):

there is a trick, you can have a 'space' in your textfields, so that problem will be solved .

Comment: bro i am fresher and its two messy so i can't get deeper into it

Comment: I know, but unfortunately, there is no way to do that! I've searched and read so many articles, didn't find any ways!